# Can two equation have same solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If you are given two equations of degree one and two variables can they have same solution.

For example:

> \begin{align}
> Ax+By+C&=0 \tag{1} \\
> Sx+Ty+U&=0 \tag{2}
> \end{align}
>
> Where: $A \ne S$, $T \ne B$, $C \ne U$.

Can it be possible if **any** two numbers $x$ and $y$ satisfy [1] then they also satisfy [2]. 
At first glance the answer seems to be "no", but if you think about your answer then you will come to realize that "no" is, not an answer but is, "intuition". And  "intuition" can be wrong. 
If you are going to answer then please provide a proof of your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can have.

Suppose the two equations be:

$$ a_0 x + b_0 y + c_0 = 0 $$

$$ a_1 x + b_1y + c_1 = 0 \tag{*}$$

For $a_0 = \lambda a_1; b_0 = \lambda b_1; c_0 = \lambda c_1$

We have equations like this:

$$ a_0x + b_0y + c_0 = 0 $$ $$ \lambda (a_0x + b_0y + c_0) = 0 \tag {*}$$

Now, they have the same solutions.

Comment: Perhaps mention that $\lambda\not=0$ and that this is the only possible way for the two equations to have the same solution sets.

Comment: FYI - this answer used the concept of "linear dependence" but did not mention the term explicitly.

Comment: @MichaelBurr See carefully, $\lambda$ was defined such that it was not needed, otherwise $a_1, b_1, c_1 = 0$, which isn't assumed by OP

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was busy whole day just thinking about this question but I am so surprised and glad that the answer is so simple.